# How to create Emulator for new Nexus 7 2 in eclipse

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

Google has just launched Nexus 7-2 with resolution 1200x1920 and other features. Now I want to test my android app on the same but I don't have device to test.
so kindly let me know how to create emulator for new nexus 7 in eclipse using AVD Manger.

I have updated sdk tool and platform to latest and able to see old nexus 7 (800x1280 res) in avd manager.

Comment: Please let me know how to check my android app by creating emulator for new nexus 7(1200x1920) device if i dont have device ..

Answer (score 5):

### Creating a new AVD device.

1. In the Android Virtual Device Manager select "Device Definitions" at the top.
2. Select "New Device..."
3. Name it: "Nexus 7 2" or "Nexus 7 (2013)" or whatever you like.

#### Nexus 7 2 (2013) Settings:

- **Screen Size (in):** `7.02`
- **Resolution (px):** `1920` x `1200`
- **Sensors:** `Accelerometer` `Gyroscope` `GPS` `Proximity Sensor`
- **Cameras:** `Front` `Rear`
- **Input:** `No Nav`
- **RAM:** `2048` MiB

---

- **Size:** `large`
- **Screen Ratio:** `long`
- **Density:** `xhdip`
- **Buttons:** `Software`
- **Device States:** `Portrait: Enabled` `Landscape: Enabled`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android virtual device manager >> select Device Definitions >> in that select third one that is NEXUS 7s create avd. Than avd is created.

But you here is you get 800x1280. I think what ever the devices drop down there in the adding off the device that is possible.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.... but I want new nexus emulator with 1200x1920 resolution. Is the emulator not yet released by google? how to make availabe in eclipse avd manager.... thanks once again...

Comment: go to  device manager >> select Device Definitions >> in that select third one that is NEXUS 7s create avd. Than avd is created. than you can create available avd managaer

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question, he wants the device definitions for the Nexus 7 Razor.